# Count same elements in first position in nested lists

Tags: python, list, count

4 jobs scheduled on 3 machines, using nested lists [machine#, job#]

```
schedule = [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```

I want to count how often machine 3 is used.

I tried using `schedule.count(3)` but I didn't get any output and I guess it would check all elements anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use count you need to create list of machines (by extracting each machine from the pair list) and the count the occurrences of `3`, for instance something like this:

```
schedule = [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
lst_count = [ma for ma, _ in schedule].count(3)  # using list and count
```

The above approach is inefficient because it creates a list and the applies count on it. A more efficient approach is to use a generator expression as @schwobaseggl suggested, one alternative to the proposed generator is the following:

```
schedule = [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
gen_count = sum(1 for ma, _ in schedule if ma == 3)  # using a generator
```

Finally both approaches work fine if you intend to count only the occurrences of single machine, if you want the occurrences of several machines for example `1` and `3`, I suggest you use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

schedule = [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
counts = Counter(ma for ma, _ in schedule)  # using Counter
print(counts[3])
print(counts[1])
```

**Output**

```
2
1
```

**Update**

Besides the above approaches you could use a simple `for` loop and a counter variable:

```
schedule = [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]

counter = 0
for ma, _ in schedule:
    if ma == 3:
        counter += 1
print(counter)  # 2
```

**Note**

The `ma, _ = x` notation is known as unpacking. When you write `ma, _` Python expects that each element of the `schedule` list is a pair of elements. For example, `x, y = [1, 2]` assigns the value `1` to `x` and the value `2` to `y`. Using `_` simply means ignore the second value.

**Further**

1. http://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/

Comment: Thank you for your help! How would you approach the solution if you want to use IF statements? if position (0,0) == 3, add 1 to a counter? I hope I can express myself clearly

Comment: Hi Sinisa, glad I could help! I didn't understand what you mean by (0, 0) == 3? Do you want to count the machine `3` only if in a certain position?

Comment: I am thinking about checking the first position of every nested list and if that first position equals 3, then add +1 to a counter.

Comment: @Sinisa Updated the answer, see if it helps you

Comment: Thanks!!! Can you help me understand the reasoning behind the underscore _ in the FOR statement? Helping me really much, just started out !

Comment: @Sinisa Just added an explanation of the notation

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension to extract the jobs on machine #3, and then just check its length:

```
num_jobs = len([x for x in schedule if x[0] == 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

`schedule.count(3)` counts how many of the elements in `schedule` are equal to `3`. You can easily see that none of them are. After all, the elements are lists.

However, you can use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) with an appropriate generator expression:

```
sum(x[0] == 3 for x in schedule)
# 2
```

This is more space efficient than building a `list` and calling `len` on it. The summation makes use of the fact that `bool` is a subtype of `int`.